# Python Read a file, ignore comments and match text

Tags: python, regex, findall

my directory:

```
    path = "C:\Users\\alopes\\afolder\\"
```

files ending with .proc

```
    infile = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.proc'))
```

Updated code:

```
   import re
   import os
   import glob
   import numpy as np
   from itertools import dropwhile

   pklist = []
   #regex for packets
   regTel = re.compile(r'[A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+')

   path = "C:\Users\\alopes\\afolder\procs\\"
   infile = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.proc'))
   for j in infile:
       with open(j, "r") as fobj:
           dp = dropwhile(lambda x:  x.startswith(";(C)"), fobj)
           regTel = re.compile(r'[A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+')
           for line in dp:
               m = regTel.search(line)
               if m:
                   print(m.group())
```

I tried this to put m into another list. The goal is to put all the matches from each file into a list that will be used elsewhere

```
               for n in m:
                   pklist.append(n)
```

Comment: Look into `str.startswith`

Comment: Add the `;` to your expression; something like `r';(\s?[\w+._\s?]+)'`

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the lines starting with `;(C)` using `itertools.dropwhile` and then search each line:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

infile = "C:\Users\\alopes\\afolder\doc_name.ext"
with open(infile) as f:
    regTel = re.compile(r'[A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+')
    for line in dropwhile(lambda x:  x.lstrip().startswith(";(C)"), f):
        m = regTel.search(line)
        if m:
            print(m.group())
```

output:

```
HELLO_WORLD.THIS_IS_1_TEST
```

If you want to run it against multiple files and get all the lines:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def yield_matches(fles,ign):
    regTel = re.compile(r'[A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+')
    for fl in fles:
        with open(fl) as f:
            for line in dropwhile(lambda x:  x.lstrip().startswith(ign)), f):
                m = regTel.search(line)
                if m:
                    yield m.group()
```

If the comments can appear anywhere just use str.startswith as you iterate using `fileinput.input` to read each file:

```
import fileinput
def yield_matches(fles,ign):
    regTel = re.compile(r'[A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+')
    for line in fileinput.input(fles):
        if not line.lstrip().startswith(ign):
            m = regTel.search(line)
            if m:
                yield m.group()
```

Just call the function passing your list of file names and the string to pass to startswith.

```
l = some_list_of_files
for i in yield_matches(l, ";(C)"):
     print(i)
```

Comment: No worries, if all the comments are at the start, dropwhile will work, using `if line.startswith...` will work in either case

Comment: itertools.dropwhile was a great idea

Comment: I got it working with line.strip().startswith(';(C)')

Comment: Do you have spaces at the start of the string? If so `line.lstrip().startswith(';(C)')` will be sufficient you only need strip from the start

Comment: def skip_comments(infile):
    with open(infile, "r") as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            if not line.strip().startswith(';(C)'):
                yield line
for line in skip_comments(infile):
    packets = regTel.findall(line)
    for i in packets:
        print i

Comment: Your code seems simpler. Is one way better than the other?

Comment: if you only have comments at the start then the dropwhile would be more efficient as you are not doing a `str.startswith` for every line, no point if you had 1000000 lines with just a few lines at the start that were comments in checking if every line startswith the substring.

Comment: Ok. Sounds great. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I am going to update my code in the initial question could you take a look at it

Comment: I have a directory I hard code in. Then I look for files in the directory ending with .proc I want to then perform the search for the regex

Comment: then `for fle in glob(os.path.join(pth,"*.proc"))`, that will find all the .proc files

Comment: error: for n in m: NoneType object is not iterable, but I thought it was a list

Comment: nope, .group returns a single match, if there can be more than one match per line change to `findall`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex:

```
re.compile(r'^(?!\s*;[(]C[)]).*?([A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+)', re.MULTILINE)
```

- `^` anchors to the start of line
- `(?!\s*;[(]C[)])` is a negative lookahead: "not followed by  ;(C)"
- `.*?` consumes the rest of the chars until
- your pattern `([A-Z_]+[.][A-Z0-9_]+)`, enclosed in parentheses to create a group and have that value returned by `findall()`

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/CKER15127)